# How to setInterval on php?

Tags: javascript, php

```
echo '
    <script type="text/javascript">
        setInterval( myfunction , 1000);
        myfunction(){
            window.location = "../index.php";
        }
    </script>';
```

if I'm just call `window.location = "../index.php"` without `setInterval` it really works I have seen many codes but no one can help me thank you.

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: go to the homepage this "echo" exist whitin a "if". This works whit a consultation on mysql.

Comment: it works when not calling setInterval? are there any errors in console? are you using setInterval correctly? can you try defining myfunction with a function keyword before it bc I always do that.

Comment: without `function` before `myfunction(){`, it will throw an error. You need the function keyword to define a function

Comment: thank you @PatrickEvans it works now... that was shame.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect or reload webpage after certain amount of time then event can only be triggered form the client side. You can achieve this using java script and html meta tags.

**1: Using HTML**

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0";url=http://www.domain.com/new-page.html">
```

you can set the value of content to the time

**2: Using Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

setInterval(function(){
window.location = "../index.php";
} , 1000);


</script>
```

Comment: can you expand a bit on why do we need 'meta tag' , in you answer.

Comment: Your javascript example suffers the same error as op's, you dont have `function` keyword before function definition

Answer (score 0):

Redirect the page after 1 second. It runs one time

```
<script type="text/javascript">

setTimeout(function(){ 
window.location = "../index.php";
}, 1000);

</script>
```

If you write in php, use it

```
<?php
//code here
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

setTimeout(function(){ 
window.location = "../index.php";
}, 1000);

</script>
<?php
//code here
?>
```

or use setInterval instead of setTimeout